# Java Visualizer running issues ABOUT Error: non-static method numDecodings(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, visualizer

[image]

here is the full code for `LeeCode` question `91`;

I wanna run a test case in `Java Visualizer` but kept getting issues like that. Idk how to normally run an example like this to see how everything works.

```
public class ClassNameHere {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      numDecodings("2622");
   }
   
   public int numDecodings(String s) {
        return s.length() == 0 ? 0 : numDecodings(0, s);
    }

    private int numDecodings(int p, String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        if (p == n) return 1;
        if (s.charAt(p) == '0') return 0;
        
        int res = numDecodings(p+1, s);

        if (p<n-1 && (s.charAt(p) == '1' || s.charAt(p) == '2' && s.charAt(p+1) < '7'))
            res += numDecodings(p+2, s);
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

I searched in Google and saw multiple anwsers firstly for how to executing code in `Java Visulizer` even checked the videos but understood nothing; then I searched specific quetsions showed in `Java Visualizer`. Both didn't work.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Visualizer. It is a plain Java error. You are calling `numDecodings` (a non-static method) from `main` (a static method) and you cannot do that because `numDecodings` needs an _instance_ of your class. Try making `numDecodings` static.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call numDecodings, which is a nonstatic method, from a static context (the `main` method). Since you don't need a nonstatic context for your numDecodings methods to work, you can just add a `static` to their definitions: `public int numDecodings(String s)` -> `public static int numDecodings(String s)`